# setOnClickListener - not called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use fragments, setOnClickListener - not called, I do not understand what is wrong

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right_panel_1, container, true);

        Button buttonStart = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.ButtonStart);
        Button buttonFinish = (Button)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.buttonFinish);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View v) {

                ////

            }
        });

        buttonFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {

                ////
            }
        });
```

and layout right_panel_1.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonStart"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_large" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFinish"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="Finish"
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_large" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollViewLog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myLog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably try adding @Override above

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
```

That's the only part i see that's missing at least :)

there's a tutorial on using fragments at http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/ you can take a look at and try doing it from scratch

Comment: @ Override is not important here, I watched it too, and not only that

Comment: Can you add the rest of the class then? Easier to spot it then :)

Comment: I looked through the example   http://neilgoodman.net/2012/03/12/working-with-fragments-on-android-part-2/ and Founded and difference ... it uses FragmentActivity but I use Activity